# new Date returns Tomcat startup date

Tags: java, linux, date, tomcat, server

I dont know how to solve this.
I have a Java Spring boot app running on a Ubuntu Server.
I have this method which should return a date with no time:

```
    public static Calendar toCalendar(Date date){ 
    
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTime(date);
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);       
      cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
      return cal;
}
```

Well, if I put:

```
Date        todayWithNoTime = toCalendar(new Date()).getTime();
```

I always get the date where Tomcat was started! Not the current date...

Anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't reproduce - are you sure that's the exact code you are running?

Comment: Absolutetly. I copied and pasted.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: How are you establishing that the date is wrong? By printing or logging the returned `Calendar` object?

Comment: I have a system.out.println in the code. I check the Tomcat log file, and I see that it's returning the date when I started up Tomcat...

The system should save the last modification date of certain object. I detected this error because when the user updates the object, the date is always the same, when it should be the current date...

Comment: Is `todayWithNoTime` a field or a local variable? My guess is that it is the former and it is initialized during the application startup.

Comment: If printing the `Calendar` and inspecting its `DAY_OF_MONTH` field, etc., you are not seeing the date the you would get from `gettime()`. It’s one of the many confusing traits of `Calendar`. Not that it in itself explains your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what I was doing wrong:

This line was at the top of the controller class, out of the methods:

```
Date        currentDate = Mydates.toCalendar(new Date()).getTime();
```

And later the method that uses that variable:

```
private void updateObject(Object object) {
   ...
   object.setDate(currentDate);
   objectService.save(object);
}
```

That way was wrong. I guess it was caching the result... don't you think?

Now it's working if I don't use the variable and call the function directly from inside the method:

```
private void updateObject(Object object) {
   ...
   object.setDate(Mydates.toCalendar(new Date()).getTime());
   objectService.save(object);
}
```

Thank you all for your help :)

Best regards.

Comment: Yes, this confirms what Piotr P. Karwasz already spotted in a comment yesterday. What you describe causes the `Date` to be initialized to the date when the controller object is created. When exactly that happens we obviously cannot tell, but it could easily happen when Tomcat is started, for example (unless you only deploy your application later). (Still thinking that you should prefer a `LocalDate` for today’s date.)

Comment: Exactly, Piotr P. Karwasz was absolutely right. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Both `Calendar.getInstance()` and `new Date()` capture the current moment. So you are either:

- Mistaken, perhaps caching the result of `Date`/`Calendar` call. See [comment by Karwasz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150667/new-date-returns-tomcat-startup-date/66182192#comment116983432_66150667).
- Or, if the date is off by a day, seeing a time zone effect.

More importantly, you are using *terrible* date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Never use `Date`, never use `Calendar`. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP gave up on those classes when adopting JSR 310. So should you.

## `LocalDate`

If you want to represent a date-only value, without a time-of-day, and without a time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

To capture the current date, you must specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. The date can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US. If you omit the time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. I recommend always being explicit.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

With that code in your Servlet code running on Tomcat, you will get the current date.

## Example servlet

Here is an entire working Servlet.

```java
package work.basil.example.DemoWebApp;

import java.io.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet ( name = "todayServlet", value = "/today" )
public class TodayServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public Instant whenServletInitialized ;
   
    public void init ( )
    {
        this.whenServletInitialized = Instant.now() ;
    }

    public void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println( "<html><body>" );
        out.println( "<h1>" + "Today" + "</h1>" );
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );  // or ZoneId.systemDefault()
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
        out.println( "<p>Current date in time zone " + zoneId.toString() + " is " + today.toString() +".</p>");
        out.println( "</body></html>" );
    }

    public void destroy ( )
    {
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of web browser showing example servlet execution]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).